# system library call not working in Intel PIN Fini Function

Tags: system, intel-pin

I want to execute one shell command (`gcore $pid`) at the end of pin tool.

In order to complete this goal, I try to modify the itrace pin tool and do one simple shell command first. I add one statement `system("ls > /tmp/test")` at the starting of Fini function. Then compile the pin tool again.

Run the pin tool - itrace:

`../../../pin -t obj-intel64/itrace.so -- /bin/ls`

But there does not exist file - "/tmp/test".

Answer (score 1):

> the libc function system() is not yet implemented in PinCRT.
>   Please use popen() (which is implemented) instead.

[*source*](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/messages/12651).